# Removing extra space after awk and echo

Tags: awk

An input file looks like

```
ab 1 2
xy 3 5
```

When I use the following lines in a loop

```
NAME=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
echo $NAME "-"
```

The output is

```
ab -
xy -
```

I don't know whether that "space" between the word and '-' is caused by awk or echo. I want to remove that. I want to be sure that $NAME is "ab" or "xy" and not "ab " or "xy ".

How can I do that?

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/trim_string_bash/

Comment: the space comes from `echo`. you could use `printf` e.g. `printf "%s%c\n" "$NAME" "-"`

Comment: You should (almost) always double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "$NAME"` instead of just `echo $NAME`), so avoid parsing weirdness. This is not the problem you're having right now, but you might later... BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the echo:

```
$ NAME="foo"
$ echo $NAME $NAME
foo foo
$ echo $NAME$NAME
foofoo
```

No space:

```
$ echo ${NAME}BAR
fooBAR
```

Answer (score 2):

`echo` outputs its arguments separated by spaces. You can modify the echo statement to:

```
echo "${NAME}-"
```

From [`bash(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

```
 echo [-neE] [arg ...]
          Output the args, separated by spaces, followed by a newline. [...]
```

You could use `printf` too:

```
printf "%s-\n" "${NAME}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The space is coming from your `echo` command, but you don't need a loop if you're already using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print $1 "-"}' file
ab-
xy-
```